# How to connect database/url on Android

Tags: php, android

[image]

How to I connect the database/php files on Android Studio.
the cmricths is laravel folder.

here's the code for Android Studio..
Constants.class

```
public class Constants {

    //    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.1.144/api/";
    //    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://cmricths.spcf-partners.com/androidtest/";
        private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://cmricths.spcf-partners.com/api/";

    public static final String USER_LOGIN = ROOT_URL+"function/userLogin.php";

    //News Feed
    public static final String NEWS_FEED = ROOT_URL+"function/newsFeed.php?username=";
    public static final String NEWS_FEED_DATA = ROOT_URL+"function/newsFeedData.php?username=";
    //Section & Grade
    public static final String USER_SECTION = ROOT_URL+"function/userSection.php?username=";
    public static final String USER_GRADE = ROOT_URL+"function/userGrade.php?username=";
    //Profile
    public static final String USER_PROFILE = ROOT_URL+"function/userProfile.php?username=";


    }
```

The error is it cannot connect on database/php file..
When I run on my phone it always "No Connection".

I'm using url..

`private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://cmricths.spcf-partners.com/api/";`

Comment: you should make that API live or give the path of localhost and make sure your phone and computer connected to same network

Comment: what if the database is online? how to call on it? because the files is under subdomain. @JinsLukose

Comment: in order to call API you should use any network library like volley or retrofit